# How to convert a Hive SQL script to a Spark SQL Synapse Notebook

Tags: azure-synapse

I have a large number of Hive SQL scripts that I want to import into Azure Synapse Analytics to run as Spark SQL notebooks.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Synapse notebooks are json files with lots of extra information.

Comment: There is a [notebook API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/data-plane/notebook/create-or-update-notebook) which looks fun but I haven't tried it myself.  Let me know how you get on!